# join same table twice sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Notes:

[image: Note Table]

I want to show like this:

[image: result table]

```sql
select n1.note_ecrit, n1.note_tp, n1.note_total, n2.note_ecrit, n2.note_tp, n2.note_total
from Notes n1
     inner join Notes n2 on n1.cne = n2.cne
```

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Comment: Ok I have  Table Note Like Picture 1 I whont to get note first session and second session in same row not in two rows

Comment: Please avoid linking to images and add your example as formatted text, it makes it much easier to help.

Comment: Ok I have Table Note Like Picture 1 I whont to get note first session and second session in same row not in two rows

Comment: you can use the union-all. like this:
`with t1 as (select n1.note_ecrit, n1.note_tp, n1.note_total, n2.note_ecrit, n2.note_tp, n2.note_total
from Notes n1
     inner join Notes n2 on n1.cne = n2.cne);
select n1.*
union all
select n2.*`, something like tha. plea read this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can you explain please

Comment: it s give me errorMsg 8156, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 1
La colonne 'note_ecrit' a été spécifiée plusieurs fois pour 't1'.
Msg 107, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 2
Le préfixe de colonne 'n1' ne correspond ni au nom de table ni au nom d'alias utilisés dans la requête.
Msg 107, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 2
Le préfixe de colonne 'n2' ne correspond ni au nom de table ni au nom d'alias utilisés dans la requête.

Comment: The code you have: what doesn't work?

Comment: yes i want in the same row

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, hopefully I understand it correctly. If you're after listing the columns manually one after another, the simplest (far from the best!) solution is to simply use nested query:

```
SELECT n1.note_ecrit, n1.note_tp, n1.note_total, 
       (SELECT n2.note_ecrit FROM Notes n2 on n1.cne = n2.cne) as note_ecrit, 
       (SELECT n2.note_tp    FROM Notes n2 on n1.cne = n2.cne) as note_tp,
       (SELECT n2.note_total FROM Notes n2 on n1.cne = n2.cne) as note_total
FROM Notes n1
```

Note: You don't have to wory much about performance, querying 3 separate columns 3 times. SQL server will in most casses construct the query in a way, that it will internally query the record only once. But it's not granted; when performance is critical, always test options for the best result.

A better way in some cases might be to use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function of the SQL server to list the values into one result field, where such output format is acceptable.

Comment: That's really not true, if you have three joins on the same table then 3 joins will be executed. The same applies for correlated subqueries such as the above. There are no circumstances I am aware of that the optimizer will merge *separate* joins into one (certain joins can be eliminated, but not here as a column is being selected).

Comment: *I don't feel like I can disprove or confirm what you wrote*. I've been coding SQL with very classic and conservative methods in past, but I had a contractor SQL experts multiple times visting me over the years to advice on the huge processes working with large datasets and they told me not to wory about this (and some other) particular thing and explained why. I basically tune my processes based on experience and if I have lack of it, on trial and error. Most of the times it just works.

Comment: ...Recently, I had even a case, where `ORDER BY CONCAT(LastName,' ',FirstName)` was significantly **faster** then `ORDER BY LastName`. The first phrase was used in the query already, while that single column was not. One could most likely use execution plan to check. I can't use them, though.  ...but as I said, I'm not arguing :-). I think the chance that it would cause problems to this particular OP is limitely close to zero.

Comment: It does indeed usually just work, there are many, many tricks the optimizer has up its sleeve, such as join commutation and elimination, transforms between joins and applys, predicate pushdown. This is not one of them. But your code may still be more performant than aggregation, depends on indexing. And your example of `ORDER BY` is interesting, I would have liked to see the execution plans on that. Was a persisted computed column involved? I would take consultant "SQL experts" with a pinch of salt, they often seem to think that `NOLOCK` is the answer to everything.

Comment: I modified (earlier on) my answer (to test if performance required), to hopefully avoid misleading people, in respect to your comments. Indeed, there's a computed column `FullName`, which was supposed to do just that, but someone did not put much thought into that and reversed the order, using `CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) isntead, which is nearly useless, can't be ordered properly. So yes, there's a persistant computed field, but I couldn't use it. As for experts :-), they were not of much help to me but some very tech details like this, above my game, where I cautiously trust them.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  Just include `id_session` as well:

```
select n1.note_ecrit, n1.note_tp, n1.note_total, n2.note_ecrit, n2.note_tp, n2.note_total
from Notes n1 join
     Notes n2
     on n1.cne = n2.cne
where n1.id_session = 1 and
      n2.id_session = 2;
```

Comment: he get duplacted data

Comment: @bx1 . . . Not based on the sample data in the question.  You would seem to have a different question from the one asked here.